# Download Python module to live distro

Tags: live-usb

I am using live distro for some experiments.

I need to have **psutil** module in Python3, but default live distro doesn't contain it.

And if I download it, next boot it will be deleted (logically).

Is there another way than download it and manually insert into some folder on USB?

Comment: You have to create a persistent usb. What distro are you using?

Comment: Kali Live distro. I wondered about it, but it means that I will have to every boot move psutil.py module into my Python folder, does not it?

Comment: No, a usb with persistence behaves like a regular installed OS.

Comment: See [https://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-persistence](https://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-persistence)

Comment: Thanks, but they choose **boot with persistence** in Kali GRUB and I have own GRUB with multiple systems.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you. Having GRUB with multiple systems is not a problem for persistence, at least not in the distros I tried (haven't tried kali :)). I will download it and see if I can be more helpful, I have my own usbs with distros and persistence and it will be nice to have kali.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Let me know please.

Comment: I will do a complete guide on how add persistence to kali, my own method, but it will take me a while. Stay tuned :).

Answer (score 0):

## Kali with persitence (my method)

> I'll be editing the answer periodically, adding the details of the steps. It's a long guide.

#### TL;DR

1. Install `grub-efi-amd64`
2. Format a USB with two partitions, a FAT one and a EXT4 one. The latter must be named **persistence** and flagged as bootable.
3. Install GRUB on the first partition.
4. Copy kali ISO into the first partition.
5. Mount the ISO and copy the first menuntry of the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` into the USB `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.
6. Add at the top of the latter file:

   ```
   set root='(hd0,1)'
   ```
7. Modify the menuentry adding at the top

   ```
   set iso_file=/<kali name>.iso
   loopback loop $iso_file
   ```

   - Add this parameters on the kernel line

     ```
     persistence findiso=$iso_file
     ```
   - Replace `linux /live` for `linux (loop)/live`. The same with `initrd`.
8. Add a file in the second partition named `persistence.conf` with the content `/ union`.